# Stimulate gravity intro-coding assassignment

Tags: java

Greeting. I am trying to make a code that display a blue ball dropping from the top, bounce up, and decrease its max point every time until it stays on the "floor." The code below somehow allows the ball to bounce while fails to decrease its max point. The ultimate goal of this project is to stimuale a gravity environment, and it will be great if the ball can change its color every time it bounces. Thank you for your time :)

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.*;
import static java.lang.Math.sin;

public class FINAL extends Applet implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    int y = 0;
    int a = 1;
    int h;
    // int p = 5;

    // Setting size of AppletViewer in the init method
    public void init() {
        setSize(400, 300);

    }

    public void start() {
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread(this, "New Thread");// New side Thread created on
                                                // start of applet.
            t.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (t != null) {
            t = null;// On stop of applet the created thread is destroyed.
        }
    }

    // Implementation of method run() of Runnable interface.
    public void run() {
        Thread t1 = Thread.currentThread();
        while (t == t1) {
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100); // slepp 100 ms
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(100, h, 20, 20);

        System.out.println("y =" + y);
        System.out.println("a =" + a);
        // System.out.println("p = " +p);

        if (y < 290) {
            a = a + 1;
            y = y + a;
            h = y;
        } else if (y > 290) {
            a = a - 1;
            h = h - a;
            y = y + a;
        }
        // else if (y>=574){
        // a = a+1;
        // h = h+a;
        // }
    }

}
```

Comment: So you're looking for someone to do the physics calculations for you?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen nah, i do know the kinetic equations. I just want to make the ball bounces like there's gravity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
public class FINAL extends Applet implements Runnable
{
    Thread t;
    double a = 9.81;              // Play with the acceleration
    double h = 290.0;
    string currDirection = "down";  // Add current direction
    double timeMoving = 0.0;      // Time in each direction
    double speed = 0.0;           // Add speed
    double maxHeight = 290.0;          // Add first maxHeight

    // ...

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(100, h, 20, 20);

        //System.out.println("p = " +p);

        // time is 100ms = 0.1s
        timeMoving += 0.1;

        if (currDirection == "down")
        {
            h = 1/2*a*Math.pow(timeMoving,2);

            if((maxHeight-h) <= 0)
            {
                currDirection = "up";
                speed += -1 * a*(timeMoving);
                timeMoving = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (currDirection == "up")
        {
           h = speed*timeMoving + 1/2*a*Math.pow(timeMoving,2);
           double currentSpeed = speed + a*timeMoving; 

           if (currentSpeed >= 0)
           {
               maxHeight = h;
               currDirection = "down";
               speed = 0;
               timeMoving = 0;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I know your idea, but the "h" is double, and for some reason, it can't be applied to the y-axis of the blue ball :(

Comment: if `h` is double you can always use `h = (int) h;` to drop the decimal part and convert to `int`. Although it is only necessary for the `fillOval()` function I guess. It was 7:00 am when I wrote the answer and I didn't sleep beforehand so errors are likely to arise. Though you want to have real physics in your script as that is what makes the ball movement _feel_ real. If it is falling too fast/slow play with the acceleration `a`.

Comment: Yes! It works now. Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem, glad to be able to help.